# How can I make a public array?

Tags: c#, arrays, sqlite

I have a problem setting the array Energy[] to public. I need to use the array in the Timer_Tick event. I've set the arrays to int and tried to make them public without success.

Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SQLite;

namespace Project
{
    public partial class FrmGame : Form
    {
        private string team;
        private string p;
        private List<DataGridViewRow> selected;
        public FrmPartida(string team, List<DataGridViewRow> selected)
        {
            this.selected = selected;
            InitializeComponent();
            this.team = team;

            this.ProgressBar.Value = 0;
            this.timer1.Interval = 100;
            this.timer1.Enabled = true;


            try
            {
                SQLiteConnection ocon = new SQLiteConnection(Config.stringConnect);
                dataSet1.Clear();
                SQLiteDataAdapter a = new SQLiteDataAdapter("Select * From players WHERE Teamplayers = '" + team + "'", ocon);
                a.Fill(dataSet1, "players");
            }
            catch (SQLiteException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("There was an error");
            }

            Statistics(dataSet1, time);
        }

        public void Statistics(DataSet dataset, string team)
        {
            SQLiteConnection ocon = new SQLiteConnection(Config.stringConnect);
            DataTable table1 = dataset.Tables[0];

            string[] PlayerName = new string[6];
            int[] Strength = new int[6];
            int[] Energy = new int[6];
            try
            {
                if (tabela1.Rows.Count != 0)
                {
                    players = selected.Select(r => r.Cells[1].Value.ToString()).Take(6).ToArray();
                }
                if (table1.Rows.Count != 0)
                {
                    Strength = selected.Select(r => int.Parse(r.Cells[3].Value.ToString())).Take(6).ToArray();
                }
                if (table1.Rows.Count != 0)
                {
                    Energy = selected.Select(r => int.Parse(r.Cells[3].Value.ToString())).Take(6).ToArray();
                }

                int time = int.Parse(timer1.Interval.ToString());
                int count = int.Parse(ProgressBar.Value.ToString());
                int Strength1 = Strength[0], Strength2 = Strength[1], Strength3 = Strength[2], Strength4 = Strength[3], Strength5 = Strength[4], Strength6 = Strength[5];
                int Energy1 = Energy[0], Energy2 = Energy[1], Energy3 = Energy[2], Energy4 = Energy[3], Energy5 = Energy[4], Energy6 = Energy[5];
                int PlayerStatistics1, PlayerStatistics2, PlayerStatistics3, PlayerStatistics4, PlayerStatistics5, PlayerStatistics6;

                if ((count / 4) == time)
                {
                    for (Energy1 = 100; Energy1 > 1; Energy1--)
                    {
                        PlayerStatistics1 = Strength1 * Energy1 * time;
                    }
                }
                PlayerStatistics1 = Strength1 * Energy1 * time;
                PlayerStatistics2 = Strength1 * Energy1 * time;
                PlayerStatistics3 = Strength1 * Energy1 * time;
                PlayerStatistics4 = Strength1 * Energy1 * time;
                PlayerStatistics5 = Strength1 * Energy1 * time;
                PlayerStatistics6 = Strength1 * Energy1 * time;

                if (this.ProgressBar.Value == 180)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(""+Energy1+"");
                }
            }
            catch (SQLiteException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("There was an error");
            }
        }

        public void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
            if (this.BarraTempo.Value < 180)
            {
                this.BarraTempo.Value++; 
                if (BarraTempo.Value == 180)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(""+Energy1+"" ); //"Energy1" needs to appear on this messagebox. 
                    FrmBreak f1 = new FrmBreak(this.time, selected);
                    f1.ShowDialog();
                    this.Hide();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ProgressBar.Enabled = false;
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

If anyone knows how to solve this, please let me know.

Thank you,

Gianlucca.

Comment: Suggest you cut down your code to a short, self-contained example. Nobody wants to read the rest of your code.

Comment: that array is declared inside a function, to be public it needs to be a class member

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `Energy` is a local variable. Local variables don't have access modifiers, since only the method execution has access to them. Consider making it a field instead, like `team` and `selected` for example.

Some side notes: following naming conventions, variables start with a lower case letter, for example `energy`. Also, once you make it a field, there's no need for it to be anything other than `private` if you just need another method in the class to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Because your `Energy` array is declared inside a function it can only be accessed from inside that function i.e. it doesn't exist outside of `public void Statistics`.

To make the array public you need to declare it at the beginning of the class like so:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SQLite;

namespace Project
{
    public partial class FrmGame : Form
    {
        private string team;
        private string p;
        private List<DataGridViewRow> selected;

        //Declare the array here with the public access modifier***
        public int[] Energy = new int[6];

        public FrmPartida(string team, List<DataGridViewRow> selected)
        {
            //Code removed for clarity
        }

        public void Statistics(DataSet dataset, string team)
        {
            //Code removed for clarity
        }

        public void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
            //Code removed
        } 
    }
}
```

That said, instead of declaring it as a public field you should look into using an [accessor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms228503.aspx) (A "get" method).